# Sass use variables to set animation property

Tags: css, sass

I have an animation that gets applied to all the `.wave` children of an element:

```
.waves > .wave {
    animation: wave 0.5s 2 alternate;
}
```

And I am using a Sass for loop to cycle through all of the waves and apply a property, say, `animation-delay`.

```
@for $i from 1 to 31 {
  .wave:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: 0.5s * $i;  
  }
}
```

I want to set a variable using `$i` that gets used in the keyframes.

```
@for $i from 1 to 31 {
  .wave:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    $max: 0.8 * $i;  
  }
}

@keyframes wave {
  from {
    transform: scaleY(0); 
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleY($max);
  }
}
```